# How to correctly split a signal in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, signals, signal-processing

I am currently struggling to correctly split a signal within Matlab. 
If I have a audio signal of assume `3` seconds long with a sample rate `fs` and I want to further use the fragment from second `2` to the `3rd` second, how can I achieve this?
Some pseudocode:

```
[y,fs] = audioread('Aaaaaaa.wav');       
N = length(y);
y_sub =...%get a 1 second long fragment of the original signal starting from 2 seconds
```

I hope that it's clear what I'm trying to achieve?

Many thanks Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of time and use it in your code,

```
[y,fs] = audioread('Aaaaaaa.wav');       
N = length(y);
t = (0 : N-1)/fs;
y_sub = y((t>1)&(t<=3));
```

Or you can work directly with samples,

```
t1 = 1;
t2 = 3;
sample1 = t1 * fs + 1;
sample2 = t2 * fs + 1;
y_sub = y(sample1:sample2); % Its 1<=t<=3
```

The `+1` is used because `t` starts from `0` while samples start from `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain the last line to me? I'm not quite sure if I correctly understand it.

Comment: @user3488736 It selects the values of `y` where `1<t<=3` which is what you want.